# Managing NSStoreType changes between debug and release builds

Tags: cocoa, core-data, debugging, release

`NSXMLTypeStore` is used when starting Core Data backed application by default because it's good for debugging purposes. But practice dictates that developer should use either `NSBinaryStoreType`, `NSInMemoryStoreType` or `NSSQLiteStoreType` store types in release builds.

How do you manage changes between debug and release builds? I believe that changing store type from `NSXMLTypeStore` to, say, `NSBinaryStoreType` in code on each release is kinda cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional `#define` statement in your header file:

```
#if DEBUG
#define NSMyTypeStore  NSXMLTypeStore
#else
#define NSMyTypeStore  NSBinaryStoreType
#endif
```

And then in your code, use the `NSMyBackingStore` definition where you need a `NSStoreType`.